# Rails, dirty objects causing rollbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_update :guest_upgrade

  def guest_upgrade
    # If the user changed their email that means they were a guest, and are no longer.
    # Likely triggered from the Registrations#Update controller
    if self.email_changed?
      self.guest = false
    end
  end
```

This is causing rollbacks, here is the log with the above in play:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-18 14:54:00 -0700
  Processing by RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x+u1DSDanU2QXK/q0=", "user"=>{"fname"=>"xxxxx", "lname"=>"xxxx", "email"=>"xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create my account", "fb_access_token"=>"", "fb_uuid"=>""}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com') AND ("users".id <> 5) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Authentication Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "authentications".* FROM "authentications" WHERE "authentications"."provider" = 'facebook' AND ("authentications".user_id = 5) LIMIT 1
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.9ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "authentications".* FROM "authentications" WHERE "authentications"."provider" = 'facebook' AND ("authentications".user_id = 5) LIMIT 1
Rendered registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (107.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 484ms (Views: 111.7ms | ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)
```

Yet if I comment out the guest_upgrade it works fine:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-18 14:55:23 -0700
  Processing by RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxx+u1DSDanU2QXK/q0=", "user"=>{"fname"=>"XXXX", "lname"=>"XXXX", "email"=>"xxxx@gmail.com"}, "commit"=>"Save Changes"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'xxxx@gmail.com') AND ("users".id <> 5) LIMIT 1
  AREL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "fname" = 'XXXX', "lname" = 'XXXX', "email" = 'xxxx@gmail.com', "updated_at" = '2011-07-18 21:55:23.817142' WHERE "users"."id" = 5
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
  SQL (37.9ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 780ms
```

Am I using the dirty objects incorrectly?

All I want to do is, when User is updated, if the user changes there email, change the user.guest field to false.

Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Do you have any validations that may be failing once you set `guest` to false?

Comment: none as it requires fname and lname which are being set with the update

Comment: I think the problem is here... WHERE ("users"."email" = 'booo@gmail.com') AND ("users".id <> 5) LIMIT 1 for some reason it is looking up by EMAIL address which does not yet even exist in the db... which is why nothing is found

Answer (score 0):

I think I've had this problem before. I believe what's happening is it's returning false; try adding an explicit return like so:

```
if self.email_changed?
  self.guest = false
  return true
end
```

Check out the section marked Canceling Callbacks at [ruby on rails.org api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). It reads:

> Canceling callbacks
>
> If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the
>   associated action are cancelled. If an after_* callback returns false,
>   all the later callbacks are cancelled. Callbacks are generally run in
>   the order they are defined, with the exception of callbacks defined as
>   methods on the model, which are called last.

I know I'm late but I hope this helps!